# How to determine the correct 'audience' and 'uri' when using OAuth 2.0 JSON Web Token (JWT) Bearer Token Flow

Tags: oauth2, authentication, connected-apps, security-token, jwt

I have correctly been able to use "OAuth 2.0 Web Server Authentication Flow" and now I'd like to switch to "OAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer Token Flow".

I wrote a test application in Node.js with the values two values:

```
audience: 'https://instance.salesforce.com'
```

and

```
uri: 'https://instance.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token'
```

The response that is coming back is stating:

```
null
400
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"audience is invalid"}
```

Also, when I look at the Salesforce Dashboard Login History, I can see "Failed: Audience Invalid".

The question I have is, how do I determine the correct 'audience' and 'uri' value.  At the moment, I am using the sandbox.

Comment: The help article about [JWT Token Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5) is a great resource for identifying values that are acceptable for the audience and the URI for the target endpoint. Are you using values shown in the documentation and receiving errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need audience for the  oauth 2.0 JWT bearer token flow and for the salesforce sandbox the value is always https://test.salesforce.com .

You don't need uri for this flow .The below document is a great resource for this

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5

Comment: Thank you, in my case I need the audience value to be **https://test.salesforce.com** and it I post it to **https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token**.

Comment: Is this URI different for a full org? for example, if my full org's URL is something like "https://<company name>--full.my.salesforce.com".  I'm using "force:auth:jwt:grant --clientid XXXXX  --jwtkeyfile server.key --setdefaultdevhubusername -u <Username>  -r https://<company name>--full.my.salesforce.com" command and getting this error "Error authenticating with JWT config due to: audience is invalid"

Comment: It is login.salesforce.com or test.salesforce.com for sandbox

Comment: Sounds like this is the same for enhanced domains?